# How to get multiple Facebook Like buttons to show and hide in responsive layout

Tags: css, facebook, responsive-design, facebook-likebox

In my design I'm moving the Like button to the footer at small screen sizes. In Chrome this works dandy by having multiple calls to the widget. In other browsers, the visible Like button hides properly, but the other one doesn't load on resize.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kc3r2

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    #header .fb-like {display: none;}
    #footer .fb-like {display: block;}
}

<div id="header">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `visiblity` instead of `display`:

```
#footer .fb-like { visibility:hidden; }

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    #header .fb-like { visibility:hidden; }
    #footer .fb-like { visibility:visible; }
}
```

Comment: Visibility leaves the element in the DOM, so I'd also have to toggle sizing. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Great, good luck on your project. Could you accept the answer? :-)

Comment: Patience, young buck. :-)